# invalid use of void expression C

Tags: c, punteros, pilas

Estoy haciendo un programa que me compare 2 pilas y me genere una tercera con los numeros que tienen en comun. Pero cuando llamo a la funcion apilar, la cual dentro tengo como parametro despilar me dice que es un error. Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es desapilar una pila e ir apilando en otro o en un auxiliar. Queria saber que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? La verdad que  puede ser por el uso de punteros el cual se me dificulta un poco entender.

```
void apilar(tpila **p, int n) {

    tpila *nodoNuevo = generaNodo(n);
    nodoNuevo->sig = *p;
    *p = nodoNuevo;
}

void desapilar(tpila **p, int *n) {
    tpila *aux;

    if(*p!=NULL) {
        *n=(*p)->dato;
        aux=*p;
        *p=aux->sig;
        free(aux);
    } else
        printf("PILA VACIA");
}

void comparar(tpila **a, tpila **b, tpila **c) {
    int n;
    tpila *aux, *aux2;
    inicializar(&aux);
    inicializar(&aux2);

    while(!vacia(*a)){
        while(!vacia(*b)) {

            if((*b)->dato==(*a)->dato) {
                apilar(&(*c), desapilar(&(*b), &n));
            } else {
                apilar(&aux, desapilar(&(*b), n));

            }
        }
        apilar(&aux2, desapilar(&(*a), &n));
        while(!vacia(aux)) {
            apilar(&(*b), desapilar(&aux, &n));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Pero cuando llamo a la funcion apilar, la cual dentro tengo como parametro despilar me dice que es un error.

Aquí invocas la función:

```
apilar(&aux2, desapilar(&(*a), &n));
```

A continuación la declaración de la función `apilar`:

```
void apilar(tpila **p, int n)
```

Es decir, el primer parámetro debe ser un puntero doble y el segundo un entero. Da la casualidad de que el parámetro `n` es el valor devuelto por `desapilar`. Vamos a ver la declaración de la función `desapilar`:

```
void desapilar(tpila **p, int *n)
```

Vaya, resulta que `desapilar` no devuelve nada. ¿Cómo se convierte un `void` en un `int`? No es posible, aquí el milagro de los panes y los peces no se va a poder reproducir.

¿Solución? Tendrás que hacer dos llamadas independientes:

```
desapilar(&(*a), &n);
apilar(&aux2, n);
```

O eso o modificas `desapilar` para que devuelva un entero.

Comment: Buenas! Acabo de ver esta respuesta, pero si la hubiera visto antes me solucionaba el problema. Era exactamente lo que decís, así que muchas gracias!!